# How to send a response to dialogflow later

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using dialogflow by google to create a bot.

When my user ask my bot for a report with several parameters, I need to create the report and send him the link to download it.

The report is created in about 1 minute. When I send the response (JSON(fulfillmentText = "my url")) of the POST request of my webhook, dialogflow send me an error : time out.

So I need to send immediately the message "Please wait..." and then, when the report is created, send to my user a new message with the url of my report.

I am trying to use the API V2 but I cannot find in the documentation a way to send a message to a user when the POST request is already done.

Comment: you can you promise or async await if you are using Nodejs as backend server, it will make sure that after generating report it will send the final response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, the interactions with Dialogflow agents are intended to be conversational and must be initiated by the user. The [timeout](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#limits) for your fulfillments response is five seconds.

It would probably be a better user experience anyway if you get an email address from the user and send them the link there, either by asking for it with the [`@sys.email`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#contacts) system entity (be aware of privacy issues though) or by using [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/).